# Android source build error: "unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_sections"

Tags: android, gcc, g++, android-source

Am trying to build Android source and get following error:

```
host C: acp <= build/tools/acp/acp.c
host C: libhost <= build/libs/host/CopyFile.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_misc.c
host C++: libhost <= build/libs/host/pseudolocalize.cpp
/tmp/ccMWrTaD.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccMWrTaD.s:10: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_sections'
```

GCC version: 4.4.5
G++ version: 4.4.5
binutils verson: 2.20.51

Searched however not much info is available on how to take care of this error:

```
Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_sections'
```

Is there any switch I need to use during building, or a config file where I can change a setting to fix this issue??

Any pointers are welcome!